# For line in file not working with try/except

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, try-catch

I'm running in an issue trying to replace pipes with commas in a text file.

```
try:
    replacement
except NameError:
    for line in dataTable:
        newdata = line.replace("|", ",")
        output.write(newdata)
    print "NO COMMAS FOUND IN " + tableLoc + "."
```

The print statement works fine, when I try the "for line in file" loop by itself, it works as well, but I'm not able to get it to work with how I have it set up above.

Any ideas or additional information I can provide?

Comment: Did you read from the file *before* this exception? If so, did you rewind to the start of the file to read the file again? There is otherwise absolutely no reason for this code not to work just because it is in a exception handler.

Comment: Yes I forgot.... Thank you, Martijn! I've been staring at this for quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about an exception handler code block. File reading is not impaired. Something else is wrong.

I suspect you already read from the file and left the file pointer at the end of the file. If you already read from the file object, you cannot just read again and hope to see the same data, you need to *rewind* the file first:

```
dataTable.seek(0)
for line in dataTable:
    newdata = line.replace("|", ",")
    output.write(newdata)
```